# What's causing all the disk activity on OS X?

Tags: macos, mac

Occasionally my Macbook Pro will slow down as the hard drive clicks away endlessly. CPU load is low, but applications and menuitems are slow to respond. Is there a utility that can help me determine what's going on, such as the number of bytes read/written or files open/closed per process, over time?

Comment: Speculating here, but it might be something simple like `mds` updating Spotlight's index.

Comment: 9 times out of 10 spotlight is the problem.  One thing I've noticed is that if you have a bootcamp partition, be sure to include it on the spotlight blacklist or mds will seem to always be chewing on it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion regarding Spotlight. I was just now experiencing very high disk reads, threw my Boot Camp partition into the Privacy tab in Spotlight prefs, and immediately disk reads flatlined! Been driving me nuts for months.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

From `man iotop`:

> iotop tracks disk I/O by process, and
>   prints a summary report that is
>   refreshed every interval.
>
> This is measuring disk events that
>   have made it past system caches.
>
> Since this uses DTrace, only the root
>   user or users with the dtrace_kernel
>   privilege can run this command.

This may not be precisely what you want - but it's a ksh script which wraps around dtrace, so you should be able to figure out how to make dtrace do what you need, if iotop doesn't handle it by default.

However, something like `iotop -C 5 12` should give you something to start with: it will output 12 samples, each 5 seconds long.

Comment: Pretty good. `iotop -C 5 12` is a good way to get a summary of what's going on.

Answer (score 51):

You can also use `fs_usage` to get a blow-by-blow account of what apps are hitting the disk.

Comment: Oooh, this is hot. `fs_usage` also lets you filter network and  filesystem activity.

Answer (score 2):

I always noticed this on Saturday mornings, and it turned out to be [`locate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/locate.1.html), which updates its database at 3:15am on Friday nights.

I tried disabling its `launchd` configuration (in `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist`), but it still ran anyway, so I just moved `/usr/libexec/locate.updatedb` out of the way. Problem…mitigated.

Answer (score 1):

It might be the OS paging to virtual memory instead of something application specific. You might try quitting less frequently used applications or at least restarting some applications that like to build up in-memory caches over time (e.g. Safari). Check out the various per-process memory statistics with *Activity Monitor* to find likely culprits. If quitting some memory intensive applications seems to temporarily alleviate the problem, you might try adding RAM.

If the disk activity is not paging related, you might be able to use [`fs_usage`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/fs_usage.1.html) to track it back to one or more specific processes.