# what is accessing my harddisk?

Tags: macos

My harddisk keeps crunching away, but I have nothing running that warrants this constant activity. How can I find out what is constantly accessing my harddisk?

I'm on a iMac, using Mac os x 10.6.4

Comment: Thought the tag was enough - I've added os and version :)

Comment: Spotlight indexing? Is there a dot flashing in the middle of the magnifying glass on the top right corner?

Comment: Also consider answers to this questions: http://superuser.com/questions/89266/whats-causing-all-the-disk-activity-on-os-x (looks like exact duplicate for me).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DTrace is your friend:

```
# Files opened by process,
dtrace -n 'syscall::open*:entry { printf("%s %s",execname,copyinstr(arg0)); }'
```

Here are other common commands (also listed in the [DTrace Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTrace)):

```
# New processes with arguments,
dtrace -n 'proc:::exec-success { trace(curpsinfo->pr_psargs); }'

# Syscall count by program,
dtrace -n 'syscall:::entry { @num[execname] = count(); }'

# Syscall count by syscall,
dtrace -n 'syscall:::entry { @num[probefunc] = count(); }'

# Syscall count by process,
dtrace -n 'syscall:::entry { @num[pid,execname] = count(); }'

# Disk size by process,
dtrace -n 'io:::start { printf("%d %s %d",pid,execname,args[0]->b_bcount); }'   

# Pages paged in by process,
dtrace -n 'vminfo:::pgpgin { @pg[execname] = sum(arg0); }'
```