# Monitor disk activity, á la top, or nettop (per process) on a Mac?

Tags: hard-drive, command-line, speed, monitoring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's causing all the disk activity on OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/89266/whats-causing-all-the-disk-activity-on-os-x)

I find that disk I/O is the single biggest cause of slowdowns on modern computers.. and find "Activity Monitor"'s "Disk Activity History" graph to be very useful monitoring and troubleshooting beach balls, slowdowns, and crashes, etc.

[image: Activity Monitor]

It does not, however, break Disk I/O down by process..  This is the missing link (for me) in terms of figuring out what is benign - and what sucks - the performance of my machine.  Below is top…  give me that, but with KB/s (or MB/s) instead of memory and CPU.  Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: So basically, check `iotop`.