# top equivalent to show I/O per process (per second) on mac/osx

Tags: macos, mac, io, top

Is there a `top`-like (visual) tool which can show per process disk I/O (kb/sec)?

The question was already asked at [Monitor disk activity, á la top, or nettop (per process) on a Mac?](https://superuser.com/questions/375350/monitor-disk-activity-%C3%A1-la-top-or-nettop-per-process-on-a-mac) and [What's causing all the disk activity on OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/89266/whats-causing-all-the-disk-activity-on-os-x), but `iotop` doesn't work in El Capitan.

Output of IOTOP on OSX El Capitan:

```
$sudo iotop

dtrace: invalid probe specifier
 /*
  * Command line arguments
  */
 inline int OPT_def     = 1;
 inline int OPT_proj    = 0;
 inline int OPT_zone    = 0;
 inline int OPT_clear   = 1;
 inline int OPT_bytes   = 1;
 inline int OPT_elapsed = 0;
 inline int OPT_dtime   = 0;
 inline int OPT_percent = 0;
 inline int OPT_device  = 0;
 inline int OPT_mount   = 0;
 inline int OPT_file    = 0;
 inline int OPT_top     = 0;
 inline int INTERVAL    = 5;
 inline int COUNTER     = -1;
 inline int FILTER      = 0;
 inline int TOP         = 0;
 inline string DEVICE   = ".";
 inline string FILENAME = ".";
 inline string MOUNT    = ".";
 inline string CLEAR    = "
";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to partially disable SIP to allows dtrace debug, so as to make iotop work on 10.11+:

csrutil status
show:
System Integrity Protection status: enabled (Custom Configuration).

Configuration:
Apple Internal: disabled
Kext Signing: disabled
Filesystem Protections: enabled
Debugging Restrictions: enabled
DTrace Restrictions: enabled
NVRAM Protections: enabled
BaseSystem Verification: enabled

I've personally disabled it completely, but you probably can limit yourself to DTrace restriction if you'd better play it safe.