# What process is filling up my drive?

Tags: macos, process

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s causing all the disk activity on OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/89266/whats-causing-all-the-disk-activity-on-os-x)

Does anyone know of a program or command for OS X that will show disk writes and what service or program is attached to them?

I have a Mac Pro with a drive that's down to no space available; I delete a couple files, free 2GB and then watch as the space goes down again; a few hours later it's down to 0 again.

There are no obvious programs running, and no software updates have been downloaded in the past couple weeks (at least not in /Library/Updates).  Any  easy way to find the culprit?

Answer (score 3):

Try running the `iotop`(1m) command from the Terminal. This will give you a list of processes sorted by disk I/O usage. The "BYTES" field tells you how many bytes were part of the I/O operation (whether read or write).

This was also covered in a previous Super User question, here:

[What's causing all the disk activity on OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/89266/whats-causing-all-the-disk-activity-on-os-x)

***EDIT:***  Regarding `bitesize.d` mentioned by someone else, I don't think its as useful because its purpose is specifically to track the size of *individual* I/O events per process. It's a debugging/investigative tool to see which processes are writing larger or smaller chunks of I/O at a time, and therefore which processes are making efficient use of the disk, *not* to see which processes are most actively writing the disk.

It *can* be used for the latter, but requires some extra steps. You have to tally up the histogram bins for the larger I/O sizes (value field) by multiplying the bin length by the size of the I/O operation. If you have a large number of processes performing I/O, this can get tedious really fast.

Another disadvantage is that `bitesize.d` has to gather data before it displays results since it needs to compute the histograms. Therefore, for "online" analysis of disk usage, I recommend `iotop` over `bitesize.d`.

Answer (score 2):

In Terminal run: `bitesize.d`.  It will print a list of processes that are using the disk.